# Playing video in Emgucv

Tags: video, emgucv

I'm trying to load a video to using Emgucv Caputre class.

This is my code:

```
Capture capture = new Capture(filename);
```

Very simple, except that I get a TypeInitializationException every time.
I'm trying to read an mp4 file captured using an android phone.

I read http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs and I tried converting it to avi in all forms. I tried using mencoder like this:
mencoder in.avi -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -nosound -o out.avi

But it still won't work.

Please help me figure out why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was that I loaded a project which used EmguCV dlls for x64, where my system is x86.
After switching them it worked.